# How to get data from view class in controller class

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I want to get username and password in the View class
but From the Controller Class

How can i use the method loginbtnMouseClicked by calling it from the Controller Class to get the data

```
private void loginbtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    //what should i have here?                  

}
```

View Class Code

```
 usernamefield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
 passfield = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
 loginbtn = new javax.swing.JLabel(); //Login Button is JLabel

private void loginbtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    //what should i have here?                  

}                


 /*
  *returns the username from the username field
 */
 public String getUserName(){
    return usernamefield.getText();
}



/*
  *returns the password from the password field
 */
public char[] getPass(){
    return passfield.getPassword();
}
```

Controller Class Code

```
This is what am asking..........
```

Model Class Code

Only has one method that return true if username and password are both admin

```
public Boolean isAccountHolder(String username, char[] password){
    return username.equalsIgnoreCase("admin") && password.equals("admin");
}
```

Comment: Just because you are using MVC doesn't imply there are three well-defined "View", "Controller", and "Model" classes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, not sure why a "loginbtn" would be a `JLabel`...

In your View code, you'd ideally have some ActionListener that defines the click method. You do not declare your own...

(Example code)

```
class MyView extends JPanel { 
    JTextField usernamefield = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    JPasswordField passfield = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

    Model model = new Model();

    public MyView() {
        // Here you update the View
        add(usernamefield);
        add(passfield);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        add(button);

        // Here the Panel acts as the controller, and updates the model
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.setName(getUserName());
                model.setPass(getPass());
            } 
        });
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return usernamefield.getText();
    }

    public char[] getPass(){
        return passfield.getPassword();
    }
}
```

Also, note: `password.equals("admin")` will not work for a `char[]` because an array does not equal a string. You have to use `new String(password).equals("admin")`, but if you are using plain-text passwords, that's a completely separate issue.